# How do I delete specific line and replace it

Tags: c

This is the code.

```
    FILE* fPtr;
    FILE* fTemp;
    char path[100];

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char newline[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int line, count;


    printf("Enter path of source file: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    printf("Enter line number to replace: ");
    scanf("%d", &line);

    /* Remove extra new line character from stdin */
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Replace '%d' line with: ", line);
    scanf("%s", &newline);


    /*  Open all required files */
    fPtr = fopen(path, "r");
    fTemp = fopen("replace.tmp", "w");

    /* fopen() return NULL if unable to open file in given mode. */
    if (!fPtr)
    {
        /* Unable to open file hence exit */
        printf("\nUnable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check whether file exists and you have read/write privilege.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    /*
     * Read line from source file and write to destination
     * file after replacing given line.
     */
    count = 0;
    while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fPtr)) != 0)
    {
        count++;

        /* If current line is line to replace */
        if (count == line)
            fputs(newline, fTemp);
        else
            fputs(buffer, fTemp);
    }


    /* Close all files to release resource */
    fclose(fPtr);
    fclose(fTemp);


    /* Delete original source file */
    remove(path);

    /* Rename temporary file as original file */
    rename("replace.tmp", path);

    printf("\nSuccessfully replaced '%d' line with '%s'.", line, newline);

    return 0;
```

I wanted to replace a line supposedly the content of the text file is this

```
> Andy,06/05/2000,US,0654852,254845,313132
> Fan,865644,4654654,654654,465456
> Ben,04/01/1995,SG,0674874,213454,132158
```

Supposedly I wanted to change the of Fan so I run the code above, it gave me this. I do not want this to happen.

```
> Andy,06/05/2000,US,0654852,254845,313132
> Fanny,865644,4654654,654654,465456Ben,04/01/1995,SG,0674874,213454,132158
```

And if I want to change the name of Andy it gave me this
    Landy,06/05/2000,US,0654852,254845,313132Fanny,865644,4654654,654654,465456Ben,04/01/1995,SG,0674874,213454,13215

Why it does that?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I delete specific line and replace it ?

Assume that the replacement line has a different size than the original one. You cannot do that in standard C11 (check [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) without copying the file to a new place (because you cannot overwrite a sequence of bytes in the middle of a file by another sequence of different length).

Read carefully the [documentation of `<stdio.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)

**Lines are just a convention in C:** they are ending by some end-of-line character (`\n`). A file could have a single line and contain a megabyte.

So you could use [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read lines. Or use [fgets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). In both cases you should check for failure. With `fgets` what would happen if the line is bigger than the buffer? With `getline`  what would happen with a file containing a single line of a gigabyte which does not fit into memory?

Be aware that **`stdout` is buffered** (and the buffer size could vary from one run to the next one and could be different if you use command [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)). See [setvbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) and [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush). In practice, take the habit of ending your `printf` format control string with `\n` and/or explicitly calling `fflush`

Many open source programs doing what you want already exist. [GNU ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/) comes to mind. Consider studying its source code for inspiration.

Please **read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**. If you use a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with some [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger, compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use `gdb`  to understand the behavior of your program. Specify on paper the input file syntax using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) and read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, including [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Notice that:

> ```
>    fflush(stdin);
> ```

is [**undefined behavior**](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). You should `fflush` output streams *only*.

PS. You could later read about [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) then consider using [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/).

Comment: Here is a link which might be useful for your answer regarding `fflush(stdin)` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Answer (score 1):

[`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will read from the file up to and including the newline character at the end of the line.  The `scanf` call you use to get the replacement string does not, so when you write out `newline` it does not contain a newline character.

Solutions include explicitly adding the newline (possibly with `fputc('\n', fTemp);`, or using `fgets(newline, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);` instead of the `scanf` to read your input string.

Comment: But when I do that, it won't ask for anything unless i put it in main program

Comment: I'm putting it inside of seperate function

Comment: For some reason when I use fgets it's not asking something

Comment: @Lorale Try putting `fflush(stdout)` before the fgets. Maybe scanf does that automatically and fgets doesn't. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Yes I want to use

> fgets(new,line,buffer_sizze,stdin);

but it just won't ask for input unless I put it inside of main().

When I put it inside of a function that I created, it won't ask for input from the user which is why I used scanf.

Is there a way to put it \n without asking the user to type \n.

Or any solution to why it's not getting input when I used fgets.

Answer (score 0):

For the people that has the same problem as me.
Fgets not asking for any input.
Try use getchar().
That solved my problem.
For unknown reason.